# How to enable/disable Android one-handed mode programmatically?

Tags: android

As the title, is there anyone knows how to enable/disable Android one-handed mode programmatically? I need to disable the one-handed mode from my own Android app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Android one-handed mode"?

Comment: I think ,he is talking about one-handed input.

Comment: I have  left handed screwdriver

Comment: Hi, "one-handed mode" means the feature that you can adjust the display size and layout for easier control of your phone with just one hand. If you go to SETTINGS -> Advanced features -> One-handed mode, then you can toggle on/off. I want to know how you can turn it on/off programmatically. Thanks.